# Hey folks - want to review some tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, cleanup

Over the course of the past few days, I've gone through each tag with five or fewer questions (with a few exceptions; see below) and:

- Cleaned up any existing tag wiki/excerpt content, slaying wikiplagiarism where I saw it
- Created excerpts where they weren't present and initialized wikis with, at minimum, a link to Wikipedia or the next-best alternative
- Renamed a few tags where appropriate

I would like to invite the rest of you to triage the remaining 80-ish tags - this means every tag with 6 or more questions at this time, plus the following tags that I skipped over for whatever reason (unfamiliarity with the topic, no idea what's actually supposed to be in the tag, etc.):

- [animation-mistakes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-mistakes)
- [conventions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conventions)
- [copyright](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright)
- [fillers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fillers)
- [game-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-history)
- [ghost-in-the-shell-sac](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell-sac)
- [ghost-in-the-shell](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell)
- [gundam-uc](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gundam-uc)
- [kuroshitsuji](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kuroshitsuji)
- [light-novel-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel-production)
- [meme](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meme)
- [sound-effects](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-effects)
- [tenchi-multiverse](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenchi-multiverse)
- [to-love-ru](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-love-ru)
- [tokyo-mew-mew](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tokyo-mew-mew)
- [vocaloid](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocaloid)

Basically, it would be helpful if you folks would go through the remaining tags and

1. Clean up any thing that needs to be cleaned (formatting, grammar, etc.)
2. Made excerpts reasonably concise, in line with [this proposal](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/938/1908)
3. Ensured that there was no wikiplagiarism

I'm not going to do this myself because

1. It doesn't make sense for a single user to make unilateral changes to content that will be seen by a large fraction of the site (i.e. major tags like [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto), [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production), etc.)
2. Multiple heads are better than one for this kind of thing.
3. I'm tired.

On the bright side, now that the massive backlog of excerptless tags has been taken care of, I imagine this should be much easier to keep pace with in the future.

Comment: I also did some of that with ~80 tags!

Answer (score 1):

About Ghost in the Shell…

- *Ghost in the Shell* and *Ghost in the Shell 2: Innocence* are two movies telling a continuous story.
- *GITS:SAC* and *GITS:SAC: 2nd GIG* are two anime series telling another continuous story.
- *GITS:Arise* OVAs are a prequel to all that.

I propose to divide them into [ghost-in-the-shell](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell), [ghost-in-the-shell-sac](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell-sac) and [ghost-in-the-shell-arise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell-arise) accordingly.