# Proposal: Refactoring tags community wide

Tags: discussion, tags, events

Now that SE has expanded the character limit for tags, we can review past tags and normalize them in some way.

Currently, our how we use tags and how we keep them up to date lags behind some of the other recreational SE community. We should look at doing small improvements to promote collaboration.

I would like to propose the following initiatives:

- Change abbreviations for abbreviated tags, like [ouran-hs-host-club](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ouran-hs-host-club) to [ouran-high-school-host-club](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ouran-high-school-host-club). We can use the official abbreviations for overly long LN names and adaptations of them.
- Change and keep track all romanized japanese titles to their official english equivalents (where applicable)  in a community wiki meta post
- Promote and create a consistent site-specific standard for tag wikis and excerpts. We don't get much use out of tag wikis, but we really should take advantage of them. We have so-called franchise meta tags for series, like [full-metal-alchemist-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/full-metal-alchemist-series), but it's not clear to many new users of how to use these tags and what to use these tags with (e.g.,"music" id requests with in a series need the series tag). This way we can refer new users to the wiki for an explanation than have to explain it from scratch.
- Create a bounty system for creating original tag wikis. Funded in part by me and any others that want to contribute. Bounty rewards will be be awarded based on efforts made with potential bounty rewards of between 100 and 1000 rep.
- Any other tag related changes that the community wishes to implement.

Please leave your comments feedback and suggestions below.

Comment: Just curious about the bounty for tag wiki: how will you give the bounty? Tag certainly doesn't accept bounties, so you will put a bounty on their post instead, regardless of the real purpose of the bounty?

Comment: Similar to senshin's past tag bounties. Award bounties to answers a user may have in the past for completing the country. However the theme will be a bit different.

Comment: Re: tag wikis - as a historical note, I tried standardizing these [about 3 years ago](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/937/) and basically succeeded because I had _far_ too much time on my hands at the time and went through and edited all the tag wikis myself. Of course, I didn't keep up with new tags as they were created (nor do I plan to, going forward), so our tag wikis are in a state of disrepair by now. For this to work well, it will require the community at-large to invest time into maintaining the tag wikis.

Comment: However... I no longer believe tag wikis are worth maintaining for most series tags (which are 90%+ of our tags by number if not by question count). With the exception of certain slightly confusing tags (multiverses like _Fate_, _FMA_, etc and similar cases like _Railgun_ vs _Index_) where we actually can provide useful guidance about tag use on this site, I don't think there is really much value we can add that goes above and beyond what someone can find by googling the name of the series.

Comment: I think the SE tag system does not fit our need: what we want is something like the ability to create tab groups; @senshin has a [post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1199/8486) that keeps track of the non-series tags. It's not our purpose to write a synopsis for each possible series tag out there. An excerpt is only needed if a tag is confusing, no way around it. If it's simply misnamed, we should first try to give it a better name so people won't misuse it, kind of like refactoring code and giving functions meaningful names. The excerpts are comments that are only a last resort.

Comment: @Gao (Incidentally, thanks for reminding me about that query; I've updated it.)

Answer (score 4):

One humble addition to this would be to **synonymize the shorter version to the longer version of the tag**.  I presume that this naturally follows, but I wanted to be sure to explicitly call it out in case it didn't.